# Closed-loop system with two cascaded P-controllers produces error increasing with time

Tags: control-system, pid-controller

**The task:**

I control desired angle \$\theta_{d}\$ with two cascaded \$P\$-controllers, the outer is for desired angular velocity \$\omega_{d}\$ and the inner is for desired angular acceleration \$\dot{\omega}_{d}\$.

\$\dot{\omega}_{d} = K_{\omega}(\omega_{d}-\omega)\$

\$\omega_{d} = K_{\theta}(\theta_{d}-\theta)\$

The plant and control loop are as follows:

[image]

Where \$I\$ is MoI, \$\dot{\omega}\$ is angular acceleration, \$M_{d}\$ is moment applied to the plant.

**The problem:**

Actual \$\theta\$ does not converge to the \$\theta_{d}\$ and the error is increasing with time.

[image]

**The question:**

What should I add to the control loop to make \$\theta\$ converge to the \$\theta_{d}\$ ?

Comment: Are \$ K_\omega \$ and \$ K_\theta \$ negative? For stability/convergence to zero they should.

Comment: They are positive. And according to a basic principles of PID controllers they must be.

Comment: Not sure if I am getting this wrong, but, \$ \dot{\omega}_{d} = K_{\omega}(\omega_{d}-\omega) \leftrightarrow \dot{\omega}_{d} = K_{\omega}(\omega_{d}) \leftrightarrow \omega_{d}(t) = e^{K_{\omega}t} \omega_{d}(0)\$. If \$ K_{\omega}\$ is positive that will be an increasing exponential.

Comment: Yes but I think you mix open-loop and closed-loop control. If you are interested please refer to the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FvbDbKLPBgoD5bkApEwYtbJtLLchgJ4l/view?usp=drivesdk) on p.102, chapter 4.2., Linear control.

Comment: From that paper I can say that there is a lot to improve on the question, first, nowhere you mention that the \$K\$ are diagonal matrices, and that all the other stuff are vectors. Also, you do not point out the model or at least the block diagram of the interconnections. Please, clarify the question so that people can help you **without** having to go through the paper.

Comment: @jDAQ I've updated the question. Sorry for the delay in response. Regarding the rest of your comment: 1. It doesn't matter if \$K\$ is a matrix or scalar since \$K\$ is diagonal and therefore control channels are decoupled. 2. Don't get me wrong, you don't have to go through the paper I just pointed out why \$K\$ is positive.

Comment: So, your system is a double integrator? would this represent the same system as the one in your picture `step(feedback(ss([0 1 0; 0 0 1; 0 0 0],[0;0;1],eye(3),0),[k_theta*k_omega k_omega 1]))` ?

Comment: Yes, except that feedback is in reversed order: step(feedback(ss([0 1 0; 0 0 1; 0 0 0],[0;0;1],eye(3),0),[1 k_omega k_theta*k_omega]))